# Finding the CRS when it is missing from the GeoTIFF file

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, geotiff-tiff

I have downloaded some GeoTIFF files from this site: https://cloud.ihme.washington.edu/index.php/s/Q5CGeazb4iNsDQA?path=%2FStunting%20Prevalence%20%5BGeoTIFF%5D

I need to convert these .tif files into .csv files that contain the stats in the .tif files as well as the geocoordinates. These GeoTIFF files do not include the CRS used to create them, however.

The CRS information is just missing however I try to look for it (using R, QGIS and Python...)

How can I figure out the CRS used to create these files?

Comment: Hi Grace - If you know the approximate area you can use the Find Projection processing algorithm in QGIS

Comment: I just tried one of the files and it came in as CRS 4326 and seems to line up.

Comment: Hi Baswein, thanks so much. Did you used QGIS or R? Would you be able to detail the process for just one of the files that I could copy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be confusing internal and external CRS references. CRS's are very confusing.  GeoTiffs can have the CRS baked into the file so there is no associated world file (.twf). 
In this case when I drag the file into QGIS 3.12 it reads the internal CRS and displays correctly. 
Here is a gif showing that process. 
[image]

Sometimes the CRS is actually missing in that case you can use the Find Projection tool to give you a lsit of the possible CRS's if you know the general area of your data. 
Good luck.

Comment: Thank you so much!